# How to order column in open office

Tags: sorting, openoffice

I have a column like this

```
RA1
RC4
RJ9
RA3
RA2
RA10
RD14
RA11
```

and I want to get

```
RA1
RA2
RA3
RA10
RA11
etc..
```

Not

```
RA1
RA10
RA11
RA2
etc...
```

There's any way to change the behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting a column or row that contains content that is NOT pure numbers.

The vastly easiest method is to see to that the numbers are formatted equally long, e.g, use a formula similar to:

`=LEFT(A1;2) & TEXT(MID(A1;3;100);"000")`

to generate better formatted data in a new column based on the one you've got.

result:

```
__A____ __B___ __...
RA1     RA001
RA2     RA002
RA3     RA003
RA10    RA010
RA11    RA011
RC4     RC004
RD14    RD014
RJ9     RJ009
```

If you wish to keep the display format you have in the column; sort on the generated column, and hide it (right click the column header, i.e. __B___, and select hide).

Comment: I got Err:509 on that formula

Comment: `;` may need to be changed into `,` - depending on your locale settings. This due to ultimate wisdom of OS/SW-translators.

Comment: Now it change to Err:501 =left(A6,2)text(MID(A6,2,100),"000") turns in to =left(A60,2)text(MID(A6,2,100),"000")

Comment: Re-verified! I thought I copied it from LibreOffice, but NOT so apparently.

Comment: My open office is in spanish so the functions are =IZQUIERDA(A8;2) TEXTO(MID(A8;2;100);"000") but any way I get Err:509

Comment: Solved! =CONCATENAR(IZQUIERDA(A10;2); TEXTO(MID(A10;3;100);"000"))

Comment: ... =) ... and this would have been a simple copy and paste if the translators had not touched the names of functions. " & " is equal to `CONCATENATE()`, yes. --- click on the tick beside my answer of you found it to be nicely matching your question.